# Ошибка при старте сервера jboss "Could not make local copy for file..."

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

При запуске сервера jBoss вылетает ошибка:

> ```
> [org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer][] ERROR - Could not make local copy for file:/C:/Users/ww/IdeaProjects/proj1/ktk-jboss/server/default/deploy/bsh-deployer.xml.
> ```

Нашел несколько вариантов решений в гугле, но проблему не решил, хотя возможно из-за моего непонимания английского.

```
2018-05-25 17:03:35,807 [org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer][] ERROR - Could not make local copy for file:/C:/Users/ww/IdeaProjects/proj1/ktk-jboss/server/default/deploy/bsh-deployer.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ww\IdeaProjects\ISystemsRepository\ARCH\ktk-jboss\server\default\tmp\deploy\tmp1963475294904133066bsh-deployer.xml (РћС‚РєР°Р·Р°РЅРѕ РІ РґРѕСЃС‚СѓРїРµ)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.copy(MainDeployer.java:1242)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.makeLocalCopy(MainDeployer.java:1187)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.init(MainDeployer.java:851)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:809)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сервер инсталлироавн в папке проекта или ее подпапках. Это мешает jBoss и IntelliJ IDEA управлять файлами одновременно. Вынесите jBoss сервер за пределы папок контролируемых IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Вынес отдельно, все равно не помогло

Comment: попробуй переустановить сервер в корневую папку или на другой комп

Comment: спасибо! помогло вынести в корень диска